# LINQ conditional where only when prop is not null

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line:

```
products = products.Where(p => p.Brand.Equals(s) ||
                               p.CatCodeNaam.Equals(s) ||
                               p.SubCategoryName.Equals(s)).ToList();
```

Which is fine, until there is no `SubCategoryName`.

So I tried:

```
var t = products.Where(p => p.Brand.Equals(s) ||
                            p.CatCodeNaam.Equals(s))
                .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.SubCategoryName) && p.SubCategoryName.Equals(s));
```

But if there is no `SubCategoryName`, it should just ignore it and do not filter so no empty collection.

I know that I can fix it by having the database returning an empty string `isnull(SubCategoryName,'') as SubCategoryName`, but I do not want that. I am looking for a LINQ fix.

Some test data to explain my issue:

I have an array with keywords like:

```
"car", "ford", "focus"
```

And I iterate over the keyword array with a `foreach`.

And since I do not know if the keyword is a brand, category or subcategory I have to check if it is one of them. But there are objects in the dataset `products` who have a null value in subcategory causing the first line to crash.

Comment: Why don't you want an empty collection being returned?  What do you want returning instead? Why do you think this better than an empty collection?

Comment: Simple suggestion: reverse the condition: `s.Equals(p.SubCategoryName)`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer that's it. I knew it was something simple! #friday can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the condition:

```
s.Equals(p.SubCategoryName)
```

That way it won't matter if `p.SubCategoryName` is null.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if I didn't understood properly, but wouldn't it work this way:

```
products = products.Where(p => p.Brand.Equals(s) || 
                               p.CatCodeNaam.Equals(s) || 
                               p.SubCategoryName == null || 
                               p.SubCategoryName.Equals(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: It is what he describes, as also @Farhad Jabiyev suggested. It sounds very odd, he wants to select "all those where SubCategoryName is NULL OR those that have the string in one of Brand, CatCodeNaam, SubCategoryName" fields? Then I would also do like this, just put the p.SubCategoryName == null as the first check.

Comment: @CetinBasoz it remembers me of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)